# jQuery navigation menu mouseover and mouseout second time doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Im developing a navigation menu with jQuery. There I came to the step that can slide down first sub menu and slide right second sub menu. When I mouseout It will fade out. But the problem is when I do the mouse over in the second time. It wont work. First time hover it works fine. I couldn't recognize the problem. I think the mouse out function will not stop or return fully after executing it. Can anyone give me a suggestion for this problem

My jQuery code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready( function() {
           jQuery('.box1').mouseover(function() {
            ///$(".box2").stop().slideDown('slow');
                $('.box2').stop().animate({
                   height: 50
                }, 1000);
            });

            jQuery('.box1').mouseout(function() {
               $('.box2').stop().fadeOut();
               // $(".box2").stop().slideUp('slow');
            });

              jQuery('.box4').mouseover(function() {
              // $(".box3").stop().slideDown('slow');
              //$(".box3").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 800);

              $('.box3').stop().animate({
                     width: 200
                  }, 1000);
          });

          jQuery('.box4').mouseout(function() {
              //$(".box3").stop().slideUp('slow');
              // $(".box3").hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 800);
              $('.box3').stop().fadeOut();
          });
          });   
</script>
```

My HTML code

```
<ul >
  <li class="box1"  >
    <div  class="box_sub" >Home</div>
    <ul>
      <li style="float:left;" class="box4"   >
        <div  id="box2" class="box2"  style="float:left">Sub 1.0</div>
        <ul style="float:left;">
          <li id="box3" class="box3"  style="float:left;clear:none;"  > Sub Sub 1.1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS code

```
    .box_sub { 
       width: 200px;
       height: 50px;
       background-color: #0066CC;
       color: #FFF;
       text-align: center; 
       line-height: 50px;
       font: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
       font-size: 14px;
       padding-top: 20px;
       padding-bottom: 20px;
       cursor: pointer;
    }
    .box2 {
       width: 200px;
       height: 0px;
       background-color: #0066CC;
       color: #FFF;
       text-align: center; 
       line-height: 50px;
       font: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
       font-size: 14px;
       cursor: pointer; 
    }
   .box3 {
       width: 0px;
       height: 50px;
       background-color: #0066CC;
       color: #FFF;
       text-align: center; 
       line-height: 50px;
       font: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
       font-size: 14px;
       padding-top: 20px;
       padding-bottom: 20px;
       cursor: pointer; 
   }
   .box1 {
       min-width: 200px;
   }
   ul { 
      list-style: none;
   }
   ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
   }
   li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
   }
```

[My jsFiddle link is here..](http://jsfiddle.net/ES4qD/)

Comment: First thing to note is that `fadeOut()` set's the element's `display` to `none`. You don't set it back again, so it'll never show again.

Comment: Yes, try adding `.show()` before your animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too much code for what you want

[**Try This Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/ES4qD/7/)

```
$("#nav li").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).children('ul').hide();
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown('slow');
    },
    function () {
        $('ul', this).slideUp('slow');            
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems great too.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the following :

Your boxes begin with a height/width of 0.
Then, you make them appear by changing their height/width to the value you want them to be.
After that, you use the jQuery function `fadeOut` which do NOT change either height or width.
Then, you remodify the height/width, but in fact, you don't change anything at all because you have already done it the first time, but you do not remove the `fadeOut` from jQuery.

So I think you have two solutions :

- First one, you change your way of appearing so it can match with the `fadeOut` function which modify both opacity and display css attributes (change opacity to 1 and display to none)
- Seconde one, you change your way of disappearing, so you remove `fadeOut` and instead use a custom animation function where you change back your settings to the original one.

Comment: Working Fiddle, by using `.show()` and resetting height and width in the `fadeOut()` callback : http://jsfiddle.net/ES4qD/2/

Comment: And here is a Fiddle forked from @Brewal's one where I fixed your mouse events (using mouseenter/leave instead of over/out) so the dropdown menu will not be fired anymore when hovering at the right of the `box_sub` div but not on it.

Comment: Thanks it works..Do you have any idea without fade out and putting slide left in order. fist slide left submenu 1.1 then slide top submenu 1 ..when mouse out. Now it happens in same time

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you are asking for, can you try asking it an other way?

Comment: There when I hover out from the submenu 1.0 , the submenu 1.1 and submenu 1.0 is fadeout in the same time. I want it first fade out submenu 1.1 and then fade out submenu 1.0